# How to remove whiskers from geom_boxplot() when called from a ggplotly() function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, boxplot

How do I get it so that it returns a box-plot without upper & lower whiskers? When I run this:

```
a <- ggplot(df1, aes(Name, Values)) + 
  geom_violin(width = 6, alpha = 0.5, trim = FALSE) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 1, fill = "black", colour = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_jitter(size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 6, alpha = 0.5) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle(label = "Title of Plot")
a
```

I get a boxplot without upper & lower whiskers. However when I run this:

```
ggplotly(a)
```

I get a boxplot with upper & lower whiskers. I require the plot to be interactive, but I want to remove the upper & lower whiskers. How would I do this?

Comment: You can create a `plotly boxplot` like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092591/remove-whiskers-and-outliers-in-r-plotly/72134879

Answer (score 1):

Other than starting in Plotly or removing the whiskers in `ggplot`, you can change them by modifying the `ggplotly` object `whiskerwidth` for each `type =  "box"` trace.

```
plt <- ggplotly(a)  # create a ggplotly object

invisible(lapply(1:length(plt$x$data),
                 function(k) {                # ensure it's a box trace
                   if(isTRUE(plt$x$data[[k]]$type == "box")) {
                     plt$x$data[[k]]$whiskerwidth <<- 0 # no width whiskers
                   }
                 }))
plt # check out the change
```